# Get the unicode of the char i wrote on process

Tags: c#

I have Form in WindowForm.

And I want to capture the specific char(unicode) that been wrote

I want to allowed to write only in 1 language.

as example i want to Allowed only english and hebrew in my program.

How i could do that? How i can handle when something else been wrote??

I know there

> OnKeyPress
>
> OnKeyDown

But i can `e.handle` only when English char as been writted.

How can i do it  for any languages by unicode or anything else?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `KeyPress` and check the range of the character. You can check a table of ranges for example [here](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html)

Then the code gets easy (this is all untested):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var unicodeValue = (int)e.KeyChar;
    if(unicodeValue >= 0 && unicodeValue <= 0x024F) // it's latin
      return;
    if(unicodeValue >= 0x0590 && unicodeValue <= 0x05FF) // it's hebrew
      return;
    // otherwise, don't allow it
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

You could of course make a table and helper functions (and remove those two `ifs` and put it all together) but I'll leave that to you.

Be wary: this doesn't handle copy & paste or other means of entering text in a textbox (grabbing the textbox handle and sending a `WM_SETTEXT` for example).

`KeyPress` is fine if you want to disallow character entry from a keyboard, but you should always validate your whole input on `TextChanged`.

This could be done with something like (again, totally untested and written right on the stack overflow editor, handle with care):

```
private bool IsCharAllowed(char c)
{
    var unicodeValue = (int)c;
    if(unicodeValue >= 0 && unicodeValue <= 0x024F) // it's latin
      return true;
    if(unicodeValue >= 0x0590 && unicodeValue <= 0x05FF) // it's hebrew
      return true;
    // otherwise, don't allow it
    return false;
}

private bool _parsingText = false;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if we changed the text from within this event, don't do anything
    if(_parsingText) return;

    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if(textBox == null) return;

    // if the string contains any not allowed characters
    if(textBox.Text.Any(x => !IsCharAllowed(x))
    {        
      // make sure we don't reenter this when changing the textbox's text
      _parsingText = true;
      // create a new string with only the allowed chars
      textBox.Text = new string(textBox.Text.Where(IsCharAllowed).ToArray());         
      _parsingText = false;
    }
}
```

You could also use a regular expression, but honestly, I've never done any kind of non-latin unicode regex, so I can't help there.

PS: Since the `TextChanged` event I posted reconstructs the whole string if there's any non-allowed character (and this could get slow if the string is long enough), I'd have this *in addition* to `KeyPress` handling

PS2: the reentry-prevention is not really necessary, since the string will be correct on re-entry and won't get modified, but we avoid the `Any()` check (which iterates on every character of the string, and -could- be slow if the string is very long)

Comment: ty that what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can simple validate entered text using regular expression like that

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z]+", options);     
tempo = regex.Replace(tempo, @" ");
```

And catch it on text_changed event.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question at all